# Representing channel characteristic data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, hec-ras

I have stream channel cross profiles of a small stream, as well as water depth data from dive loggers we installed the beginning of summer. There is only one dive logger in the stream. I am trying to graphically represent the change in water depth over time within the channel cross section profiles we measured, but I am having difficulty in going about it. I thought using Hec-Ras would be a good start, but being unfamiliar with the program I've become stuck.

How do I go about representing this data?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "dive logger", but I'm assuming it's a device to measure the water surface elevation. Please correct me if I'm wrong. In general HEC-RAS is best used for predicting water surface elevations, not displaying measured water surface elevations, so I don't think it's the most appropriate tool for you. Typically water surface elevation data over time is represented in a graph, not a cross section. Could you clarify what you'd like to represent?